# Using ImageMagick with "Fred's ImageMagick Scripts" UNROTATE3 I am unable to correctly crop and rotate images

Tags: linux, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to use Fred's ImageMagick Script [Unrotate3](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/unrotate3/index.php) to rotate and crop images.

I am using the following command to do that: `./unrotate3.sh -m l -f 1 -g both -t inner preview.jpg preview_edited.jpg`

preview.jpg: https://ibb.co/5x9MnrR

preview_edited.jpg: https://ibb.co/NWZT7BM

preview_mask.gif: https://ibb.co/KKwJFWH

preview_vertices.png: https://ibb.co/WVk81G5

I have also tried [Unrotate2](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/unrotate2/index.php) but wasn't successful either.

Can someone help me to get that working? Or is there something better I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed some issues with the script. So download it again. Inner trim seems to work best with Imagemagick 7 and seems to be "flaky" in Imagemagick 6 for some reason that I have not yet figured out. So here are the commands and results for trim=outer in Imagemagick 6 and trim=inner for Imagemagick 7.

Input:

[image]

Imagemagick 6:

```
unrotate3 -m landscape -f 1 -F 5 -t outer preview.jpg preview_edited_outer6.jpg
```

[image]

Imagemagick 7:

```
unrotate3 -m landscape -f 1 -F 5 -t inner preview.jpg preview_edited_inner7.jpg
```

[image]